# 1 minus percentage returns negative number

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, computed-column

I have a `sidewalk_inspection` table:

```
create table user.sidewalk_insp
(
    insp_id int,
    deficiency_length number(10,2),
    sidewalk_length number(10,2)
);

insert into user.sidewalk_insp (insp_id, deficiency_length, sidewalk_length) values ( 1, 0.0, 10.0);
insert into user.sidewalk_insp (insp_id, deficiency_length, sidewalk_length) values ( 2, 2.5, 10.0);
insert into user.sidewalk_insp (insp_id, deficiency_length, sidewalk_length) values ( 3, 5.0, 10.0);
insert into user.sidewalk_insp (insp_id, deficiency_length, sidewalk_length) values ( 3, 7.5, 10.0);
insert into user.sidewalk_insp (insp_id, deficiency_length, sidewalk_length) values ( 4, 11.0, 10.0);

select * from user.sidewalk_insp;

   INSP_ID DEFICIENCY_LENGTH SIDEWALK_LENGTH
---------- ----------------- ---------------
         1                 0              10
         2               2.5              10
         3                 5              10
         4               7.5              10
         5                11              10
```

---

I can calculate the `deficiency_percent` by dividing `deficiency_length` by `sidewalk_length`:

```
select
    insp_id,
    deficiency_length,
    sidewalk_length,
    deficiency_length / sidewalk_length as deficiency_percent
from
    user.sidewalk_insp;


   INSP_ID DEFICIENCY_LENGTH SIDEWALK_LENGTH DEFICIENCY_PERCENT
---------- ----------------- --------------- ------------------
         1                 0              10                  0
         2               2.5              10                .25
         3                 5              10                 .5
         4               7.5              10                .75
         5                11              10                1.1
```

---

Rather than calculate the `deficiency_percent` (a.k.a. 'percent bad'), I want to calculate the `condition_percent` (a.k.a. 'percent good'). I can do this by subtracting the percentage from `1`:

```
select
    insp_id,
    deficiency_length,
    sidewalk_length,
    1 - (deficiency_length / sidewalk_length) as condition_percent
from
    user.sidewalk_insp;

   INSP_ID DEFICIENCY_LENGTH SIDEWALK_LENGTH  CONDITION_PERCENT
---------- ----------------- --------------- ------------------
         1                 0              10                  1
         2               2.5              10                .75
         3                 5              10                 .5
         4               7.5              10                .25
         5                11              10               -0.1
```

---

Unfortunately, due to a quirk of the data (user input errors), the `deficiency_length` is occasionally longer than the `sidewalk_length`. While, in theory this is impossible (a sidewalk's deficiency should never be longer than it's length), in reality, it is something that happens that is beyond my control (the [application](http://www.esri.com/products/collector-for-arcgis) is not customizable).

The result is a negative number in the `condition_percent` column (see `insp_id #5`) which is not a valid percentage. Instead of outputting a negative number, I think the best way to handle negative percentages would be to output a value of `0` (0%).

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could just use `GREATEST` with `0`:

```
select
    insp_id,
    deficiency_length,
    sidewalk_length,
    greatest(0, 1 - (deficiency_length / sidewalk_length)) as condition_percent
from
    user.sidewalk_insp;
```

The above function returns 0 or calculated condition percent, whichever is greater.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant way of doing it, but it seems to work:

```
select
    insp_id,
    deficiency_length,
    sidewalk_length,
    case when nvl(deficiency_length,0) <= sidewalk_length
        then 1 - (deficiency_length / sidewalk_length)
    else 0 
    end condition_percent
from
    user.sidewalk_insp;
```